# fprintf not working

Tags: c, io

I'm testing the usage of `fprintf()` and it is not working. When I first wrote the code I forgot to add `\n` inside `fprintf()` and it worked. However, when I added `\n` at the start of "test 1 2" it stopped working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
    if( f == NULL) return 0;

    char str[4][10];

    for(int a = 0; a <= 3; ++a)
    {
        fscanf(f, " %[^\t\n]s", str[a]);
        printf("%s\n", str[a]);
    }

    fprintf(f, "\ntest 1 2\n");

    fclose(f);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and my test.txt contains ( instead of `\t` and `\n` I pressed tab and enter in the file but I couldn't manage it here)

> a b\t  c d\t   e\n
>   f g

Comment: Please describe what worked before and how it doesn't work now.

Comment: Note that you are not supposed to switch between reading from a 'for update' file stream and writing to it without an `fseek()` or equivalent unless you encounter EOF on the last read.  You should have an `fseek()` before the `fprintf()`, therefore.  (Without it, you invoke _undefined behaviour_, which means anything could happen, including 'it works, by accident'.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> For files open for appending (those which include a "+" sign), on
>   which both input and output operations are allowed, the stream should
>   be flushed (fflush) or repositioned (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) between
>   either a writing operation followed by a reading operation or a
>   reading operation which did not reach the end-of-file followed by a
>   writing operation.

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)

So add this:

```
fflush(f);
```

before your `fprintf` if you want to append to the file without deleting its previous contents, or this:

```
rewind(f);
```

if you want to overwrite the content, as pointed by your comment.

Comment: I used rewind() and it solved the problem however, fflush did not solve it

Comment: It depends if you want to append to the file or overwrite it.
rewind() sets the pointer at the first position in the file, so I guess overwrite is what you were looking for. I'll edit the answer.