# C Read and write file at the same time

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to understand the interactions between functions to read and write a file in C.

In the example, I used a file with three short lines of text inside.

If I execute the program as it is written below, NOTHING is written to the file. Why?

Moreover, if i comment out the fgets() instruction, the two fprintf are executed (and part of the first line of the file is overwritten by those commands, which is what I expecteded).

I do not get why the fgets prevents the fprintf to take place. What I think is that after the fgets instruction, the XX shold be written starting from the second line of the file. What am I missing?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define MAX 100
    #define FILENAME "file.txt"

    int main(){
        FILE *f1;
        char buff[MAX];

        f1 = fopen(FILENAME,"r+");
        if(f1==NULL) return 0;

        fgets(buff,MAX,f1); 
        printf("%s",buff);

        fprintf(f1,"XX \n");
        fprintf(f1,"XX \n");

        fclose(f1); 
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to the comments, (and this question [fprintf not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364210/fprintf-not-working)) I understand that the solution is to perform an fseek between reading and writing the file. I would like to understand, if possible, why this fseek is needed, i.e. what happens to the file pointer...

Comment: Yes, with three lines of text inside.

Comment: Is it in the right location?

Comment: Yes. The first line of text is correctly shown on the screen by the printf instruction. So the file IS read.

Comment: Do you have write access to the directory the file is stored in?

Comment: Yes. If I comment the fgets instruction, the file is correctly written. I am working on a windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: @Jongware I agree that the two questions are very similar and that one helped me a lot. However, I would like to understand WHY if I do not put fseek I get an undefined behaviour, i.e. what happens to the file pointer.... From what I understand, the pointer should move after each read or write instruction. So writing after something is read shold add the text immediately after what has been read.

Comment: Maybe you can try in on larger file. Larger than 100.

Comment: Think about it: `fgets` cannot "know" in advance how many bytes it should read. Therefore, it reads *chunks* of data -- the larger, the better (because then you are sure you get a 'whole line' sooner). Reading -- and writing -- is best done using a fixed buffer size. Now why would `fgets` *not* automatically reposition the file pointer after the last return read? Because it does not matter -- any remaining data in the read buffer will be consumed first anyway.

Comment: You've got your answer in Jongware's link. Note that the link the link links to has been updated and it now says "For files open for update (those which include a "+" sign)..." (appending --> update). It's interesting, though, that the program works according to your expectations on my Linux system (no flushing after reading needed).

Comment: @Jongware Thanks for the explaination. It is clear now. The question can be closed. Thanks also to ThorX89